# 1978 Jeep Wagoneer - Rotor problems

Tags: jeep, brake-rotor, drum-brakes, socket, parts-replacement

-I am trying to change the rotors on a 1978 Jeep Wagoneer (5.9L 4WD, Quadtrac), but in order to do that I need a special tool to remove the socket that holds the rotor, I don't know what tool that is. I asked the employees at O'Reily's but they don't seem to have a clue about what I am talking about.

Comment: Can you add a photo?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's something like this tool as you need to remove the wheel hub in order to get the brake rotor off:

[Special Tool](https://www.quadratec.com/p/crown-automotive/spindle-nut-socket-sj-j-series-5352169W?gclid=Cj0KCQjwmouZBhDSARIsALYcour19VsqbXd_71_yf-TUsiR52x23MT5Nho3zfcm-AriLK9U8G4nomlIaAmRpEALw_wcB)

[image: Special Tool]

Answer (score 0):

Your Jeep most likely came with a Dana 44 front axle with open knuckles. How ever on a vehicle that old anything is likely to have been changed. The tool @jwh20 has posted the image of is referred to as a Spindle Nut Socket. Since you mentioned O'Reillys their part number is 15002-01. I would suggest removing the dust cap from the spindle and verifying this socket will fit your spindle nut. You could also take a photo of the nut and get a match that way. There are a few sizes and pin configurations' but getting a match shouldn't be difficult now that you know what to ask for.

Comment: I lost my password a good while. Thanks, through the photos and info provided I bought the DANA 44 and was able to replace my parts. I appreciate all the comments!